# How to dynamically load items in a ComboBox using AvaloniaUI

Tags: c#, .net-core, avaloniaui

I have a ComboBox in AvaloniaUI, and I want to load the list dynamically based off the names provided by an array of another class. For example, take the following code:

```xml
<ComboBox Name="Select" SelectedIndex="0"></ComboBox>
```

```cs
public class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Note[] notes;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        AvaloniaXamlLoader.Load(this);
        notes = Utility.GetNotes();

        ComboBox comboBox = this.Find<ComboBox>("Select");
        foreach (Note n in notes)
        {
            comboBox.Items.Add(
                new ComboBoxItem()
                {
                    Content = n.Name
                }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
public class Note
{
    public string Name;
    public string NoteText;
}
```

I'm not sure of the proper way to do this in AvaloniaUI since in WPF you could just directly call that `comboBox.Items.Add()` function. However that function doesn't seem to exist when using AvaloniaUI.

Comment: Have you tried setting `comboBox.Items` to your array directly and defining a data template for the `Note` class in XAML?

Comment: @kekekeks I'm not sure I follow what you mean by that. Could you give a code example?

Comment: comboBox.Items = new List<Note> 
{ 
    new Note {Name="name", NoteText="text"},
    new Note {Name="name 2", NoteText="text"}
};

<ComboBox x:Name="Select">
   <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
     </DataTemplate>
   </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following [@kekekeks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2231814/kekekeks) comment above I was able to make this work with a few changes:

```xml
<ComboBox Name="Select">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

```cs
public class MainWindow : Window
{
    private List<Note> Notes;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        AvaloniaXamlLoader.Load(this);
        Notes = Utility.GetNotes();
        ComboBox comboBox = this.Find<ComboBox>("Select");
        comboBox.Items = Notes;
        comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

```cs
public class Note
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string NoteText { get; set; }
}
```

I just want to add that having the Notes variable as an array doesn't seem to work, so I had to change it to a list and I had to change the Note class to use `{ get; set; }` as well.